# Code sensing and color issue

Tags: xcode

I am having a weird problem, my xcode stopped changing the color of my declared method name and variables(it is still auto-complete the name), all the name appeared to be black rather than purple, it runs just fine, but it is difficult for future debugging, I've checked the Xcode Preference->Fonts and Colors, from Project Class Names to the end it appears as grayed out, seems not available. I've googled a lot but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Was it something like this?
[image]

For me the solution (which I lucked-upon, rather than deduced) was to close Xcode and restart it.  It must be a bug in Xcode.